# Como ir llenando un array con datos

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objeto

Siguiendo con un ejercicio de cargar datos de un disco que ingresa un usuario, necesito preguntar después si se quiere agregar otra pista y su duración.

Éste es mi objeto:

```
class DatosDelDisco {
    constructor(nombre, autor, codigo) {
        this.nombre = nombre,
        this.autor = autor,
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    //codigo = [];
    pistas = [];
    duracion = [];

}
```

```
// Código usado para pedir datos varios, entre ellos para pedir el nombre de la pista

const pedirDato = (mensaje) => {
    // La variable valor se reutilizará en cada dato string solicitado en el programa
    let valor = prompt(mensaje);

    // Si no se ingresa nada al solicitar el dato se disparará un alert para solicitar el dato de nuevo
    if (valor == "") {
        mensajeDeAlerta = alert("No puede dejar este campo en blanco. Por favor intente de nuevo.");

        // Se le pedirá al usuario que ingese de nuevo el dato
        return pedirDato(mensaje);
    }
    return valor;
}
```

```
// Pedir la duración de la pista 

const cargarDuracionDelDisco = () => {
    let segundos = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese la duración de la pista medida en segundos"));

    // Validación de la duración de la pista

    if (segundos < 0 || segundos > 7200) {

        mensaje = alert("La cantidad de segundos no puede ser menor a 0 ni mayor a 7200. Por favor ingrese un código válido");

        // Se volverá a pedir al usuario que ingrese de nuevo el código
        return cargarDuracionDelDisco();

    }
    return segundos;
}
```

```
// Después de ingresar la primera pista y su duración, se le pregunta al usuario si desea ingresar otra pista

function cargarOtraPista() {

    // Pistas ya tiene previamente un dato cargado de la primera vez que ingresó
    // pistas y duracion son arrays en el objeto

    pistas;
    duracion;

    for (let i = 0; i < pistas.lenght; i++) {

        let ingresarOtraPista = confirm("Desea agregar otra pista?");

        if (!ingresarOtraPista) {
            break;

        } else {
            pistas += pedirDato("Ingresa el nombre de la pista");

            duracion += cargarDuracionDelDisco();

        }

        return pistas, duracion;
    }
}

function cargarDatosDelDisco() {

    nombre = pedirDato("Ingrese el nombre del disco");
    autor = pedirDato("Ingrese el autor del disco");
    codigo = cargarCodigoDelDisco();
    pistas = pedirDato("Ingresa el nombre de la pista");
    duracion = cargarDuracionDelDisco();
    cargarOtraPista();
}
```

```
// Luego al dar clic en el botón Mostrar se imprimen el el documento los datos

 function mostrarDiscosCargados() {

    // Las variables ya tienen los datos del usuario

    nombre;
    autor;
    codigo;
    pistas;
    duracion;

    let disco = new DatosDelDisco(nombre, autor);
    disco.codigo = codigo;
    disco.pistas = pistas;
    disco.duracion = duracion;

    html = `<ul>
    <li>${disco.nombre}</li>
    <li>${disco.autor}</li>
    <li>${disco.codigo}</li>
    <li>${disco.pistas}</li>
    <li>${disco.duracion}</li>
    </ul>`;
    document.getElementById("coleccion").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: cual es la pregunta? Estaria bueno que nos digas explicitamente cual es la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Yo supongo que estas aprendiendo, así que te presento otra forma de hacerlo. Esta vez con sistema de validación generico.

Además creé una clase Pista la cual tiene una relación con Disco de 1 a N. Es decir un Disco tiene muchas pistas.

También cuando pides las pistas vuelves a usar un bucle que no es necesario.

```js
class Pista{
    constructor(nombre, duracion) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.duracion = duracion;
    }
    GetLabel() {
        return `${this.nombre} - ${this.duracion}`;
    }
}

class Disco {
  constructor() {}
  nombre; autor; codigo;
  pistas = [];

  GetLista(){
    let html = `<ul>
      <li>${this.nombre}</li>
      <li>${this.autor}</li>
      <li>${this.codigo}</li>
      <li>${this.duracion}</li>`;

      for (let i = 1; i <= this.pistas.length; i++ ) {
          html += `<li>Pista ${i} : </li>
                   <ul>
                     <li>${this.pistas[i-1].GetLabel()} </li>
                   </ul>`;
      }
      return html + "</ul>"
    }

    AddPista(Nombre, Duracion) {
        this.pistas.push(new Pista(Nombre, Duracion));
    }
}

const pedirDato = (e) => {
    let valor = prompt(e.mensaje);
    if (!e.validador(valor)) {
        alert(e.mensajeError);
        return pedirDato(e);
    }
    return valor;
}

//variable global
const disco = new Disco();

function cargarDatosDelDisco() {


    //validadores generales
    let validacionVacia = {
        mensajeError: "No puede dejar este campo en blanco. Por favor intente de nuevo.",
        validador: e => e.length > 0
    };

    let validacionDuracion = {
        mensajeError: "La cantidad de segundos no puede ser menor a 0 ni mayor a 7200. Por favor ingrese un código válido",
        validador: e => Number(e) != NaN && Number(e) >=0 &&  Number(e) <= 7200
    };
    //------------

    disco.nombre = pedirDato({ mensaje: "Ingrese el nombre del disco", ...validacionVacia});
    disco.autor = pedirDato({ mensaje: "Ingrese el autor del disco", ...validacionVacia});
    disco.duracion = Number(pedirDato({mensaje: "Ingrese la duración de la pista medida en segundos", ...validacionDuracion }));
    disco.codigo = pedirDato({
        mensaje: "Ingrese el código del disco",
        mensajeError: "El código debe ser un Número",
        validador: e => Number(e) != NaN
    });

        
    let pedirPistas = true;
    while (pedirPistas) {
        let nombre = pedirDato({ mensaje: "Ingrese el nombre de la pista", ...validacionVacia });
        let duracion = pedirDato({mensaje: "Ingrese la duración de la pista medida en segundos", ...validacionDuracion });

        disco.AddPista(nombre, Number(duracion));
        pedirPistas = confirm("Desea agregar otra pista?");
    }
        
  
}




function mostrarDiscosCargados(){
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = disco.GetLista();
}
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
<button onclick="cargarDatosDelDisco()">Pedir datos</button>
<button onclick="mostrarDiscosCargados()">Mostrar discos cargados</button>
```